# Date Parameter sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, parameters

Im looking to write a function which declares a variable @StartDate to be the first of January but the year to be the year that you run the script(current year) which means the year can change but the day and month cant.

Anyone know how to do this ?

Example code:

IF @DATE_TYPE = 'FIRST QUARTER'

BEGIN

SET @START_DATE = 01/01/'Current Year'

SET @END_DATE = 31/03/'Current Year'

END

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL 2012 and above versions,

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) 
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (YEAR(GETDATE()), 03, 31)
```

For All versions,

```
SELECT CAST('01 JAN '+CAST(DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
SELECT CAST('31 MAR '+CAST(DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) AS NVARCHAR) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this (it's better to use convert() when you define dates and not implicit conversion):

```
SET @START_DATE = CONVERT(datetime, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0101', 112)
    SET @END_DATE = CONVERT(datetime, CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '0331', 112)
```

Comment: Cheers this is exactly what I was after , just for my own record ,what exactly does the 112 at the end do ?

Answer (score 0):

In Sql 2012+, you could use [Datefromparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)

```
IF @DATE_TYPE = 'FIRST QUARTER'
BEGIN
   SET @START_DATE = datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1,1)
   SET @END_DATE = datefromparts(year(getdate()), 3,31)
END
```

If you want to get the fisrt date and the last date of a quarter, then use it

```
DECLARE @CurrentDate datetime = '2017-07-01' -- or getdate() or any date
SELECT  datefromparts(year(@CurrentDate), 
                 datepart(quarter, @CurrentDate) * 3 - 2,1) AS StartDate,
        EOMONTH(datefromparts(year(@CurrentDate), 
                 datepart(quarter, @CurrentDate) * 3 , 1)) AS EndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

If youre using SQLSERVER 2012, you can use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)

```
        DECLARE @START_DATE DATE,
                @END_DATE DATE

        SELECT  @START_DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 1, 1) ,
                @END_DATE = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), 03, 31) 

        SELECT  @START_DATE [start_date] ,
                @END_DATE [end_date]
```

Result:

```
    start_date     end_date
    ----------     ----------
    2017-01-01     2017-03-31

    (1 row(s) affected)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATETIME

DECLARE @END_DATE DATETIME

DECLARE @DATE_TYPE VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE @YEAR VARCHAR(4)

SET @DATE_TYPE = 'FIRST QUARTER' -- SAMPLE PARAMETER

SET @YEAR = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4))

DECLARE @tbl TABLE ([QUARTER] VARCHAR(50), StartMonth VARCHAR(2), EndMonth VARCHAR(2))

INSERT INTO @tbl ([QUARTER], StartMonth, EndMonth)

SELECT 'FIRST QUARTER', '1', '3'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'SECOND QUARTER', '4', '6'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'THIRD QUARTER', '7', '9'

UNION ALL

SELECT 'FOURTH QUARTER', '10', '12'




SELECT @START_DATE = StartMonth + '/1/' + @YEAR,
    @END_DATE = DATEADD(DD, -1, (DATEADD(mm, 1, EndMonth + '/1/' + @YEAR)))

FROM @tbl

WHERE [QUARTER] = @DATE_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Day VARCHAR(10) = '1stQUARTER' --Give the quarter name condiations like 1stQUARTER,2ndQUARTER,3rdQUARTER,4thQuarter 

IF (@Day = '1stQUARTER')
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) - 1 = 1
                THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
            END AS StartDayQuarter
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) - 1 = 1
                THEN DATEADD(dd, - 1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
            END AS EndDayQuarter
END
ELSE IF (@Day = '2ndQUARTER')
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) = 2
                THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
            END AS FirstDayQuarter
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) = 2
                THEN DATEADD(mm, + 3, DATEADD(dd, - 1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
            END AS LasttDayQuarter
END
ELSE IF (@Day = '3rdQUARTER')
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) + 1 = 3
                THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)
            END AS FirstDayQuarter
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) + 1 = 3
                THEN DATEADD(mm, + 6, DATEADD(dd, - 1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
            END AS LasttDayQuarter
END
ELSE IF (@Day = '4thQuarter')
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) + 2 = 4
                THEN DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()) + 2, 0)
            END AS FirstDayQuarter
        ,CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(QUARTER, getdate()) + 2 = 4
                THEN DATEADD(mm, + 9, DATEADD(dd, - 1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
            END AS LasttDayQuarter
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Enter Valid Quarter Name'
END
```

OutPut

```
   FirstDayQuarter      |LasttDayQuarter
--------------------------------------------
2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 |2017-03-31 00:00:00.000
```